# Passing complex object from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using overload 10 of `BeginForm()` where the parameters are:

1. string actionName
2. string controllerName
3. **object** routeValues
4. FormMethod method

I put my model, which is a complex object earlier passed from the controller to the view, in the third parameter.  However, I get a compilation error:

```
CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvcApplication5.Models.xxxModel>'does not 
contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and the best extension method overload 
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, 
string, string, object, System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod)' has some invalid 
arguments
```

Is there a way to post a complex object from a view to the controller?

---

**Edits:**

***My model is:***

```
public xxxModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Adddress Address { get; set; }
}
```

***My view is:***

```
@model namespace.xxxModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controller", Model, FormMethod.Post) { .....
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the BeginForm()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put your Model class inside the RouteValues params.

Look at the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) 
As stated in the help:

routeValues
   Type: System.Object
   *An object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters are retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the object. This object is typically **created by using object initializer syntax**.*

use this then

```
new { MyProp1 = Model.Prop1, MyProp2 = Model.Prop2, MyProp3 = Model.Prop3, ... }
```

Otherwise use hidden fields inside your form. The ModelBinder will map them to your model during the post

Comment: I see.  So it is restricted to simple key/value pairs?

Comment: Yes. Personally I go with hidden fields when there are lot of params to pass

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having a user fill out a form to be submitted, you can change your view to:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("actionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
}
```

Your action would accept the model as the parameter.

** Note: If the form is in the view of the action that it is being posted to, you can do:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```